# Is there a way to add OneNote-style tags in Evernote?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, microsoft-onenote, evernote

I made the switch to Evernote from Onenote a few months ago. For the most part, I like it a lot better, but there are some features I really miss.

In OneNote, I can "tag" a line of text by using these hotkeys:

This adds a checkbox (CTRL+1)

This adds a question icon (CTRL+3)

This flags line as important (CTRL+2)

This highlights line with yellow (CTRL+4)

This highlights line with green (CTRL+5)

In Evernote, I can add a checkbox using CTRL+Shift+C, but it inserts the checkbox wherever the cursor is rather than at the start of the line. I have to navigate to the start of each line to add checkboxes. And in OneNote, if I highlight several lines of text and press CTRL+1, a checkbox is added to every line. In EverNote, the entire block of text is replaced by a single checkbox.

Is there a way to configure EverNote to work like OneNote in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to automate a lot of what I do. I had exactly the same frustration as you. To make it easy I use AHK to remap a couple of keys.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> : go to start of line, add a checkbox

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> : go to start of line, add a checkbox, go to next line

The second option is the one I use when I want to add a series of checkboxes - rather than highlighting a block of text, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is used to quickly add a checkbox to each line.

The AutoHotkey script I use is this:

```
;Evernote create checkbox, new line
#v::Send {Home}^C{Home}{Down}

;Evernote checkbox create 
#c::Send {Home}^C
```

You can use AHK to automate a lot of stuff in EverNote. I use it to pull up frequently used views, frequently used documents, and to automate a clipper to clip multiple parts of a page to a single document.

Comment: @Tim_H: This is very cool. Thanks for the reply. I'm already using your script.